# Obtener id al cargar una function jquery

Tags: jquery

estoy tratando de sacar el id de una imagen al cargar la pagina nose que estoy haciendo mal e aqui mi codigo

```js
var id;
function get_id() {
 var id= this.id;
 $("#result").html(id)

}
$(document).ready(function(){


get_id()


})
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<title>Obtener id</title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body >
<div>
 <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTyyVHz8oYsN2jOMsL2Q-8so-HGNq2_wGwiuAPBkK9wtvsZRN8u" width="100" height="50" id="imagen_00" alt="" onload="javascript:get_id()"/>
  <div id="result"></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

que es lo que estoy haciendo mal ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

lo que sucede es que cuando llamas a la funcion no le pasas nada, por ende el no sabe sobre que objeto esta haciendo referencia, dicho esto quedaria asi:

```
var id;
function get_id(campo) {
 var id= campo.id;
 $("#result").html(id)

}
$(document).ready(function(){


get_id()


})


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<title>Obtener id</title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body >
<div>
    <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTyyVHz8oYsN2jOMsL2Q-8so-HGNq2_wGwiuAPBkK9wtvsZRN8u" width="100" height="50" id="imagen_00" alt="" onload="get_id(this)"/>
  <div id="result"></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

donde llamas la funcion en el thml le pasas el valor del elememto con el `this`

espero te sirva...

Comment: gracias amigo fue util!

Comment: De nada bro, siempre es un placer ayudar :)